# App crashes during creation DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, datepicker, illegalargumentexception

I'm completely new to programming on the Android platform but I'm interested in learning more of it. At the moment I'm doing this with the aid of a step by step handbook. Just to get myself familiar with the programming environment. I have knowledge of the Java language although I would not go as far by saying I'm good at it.

As for the problem, what I'm creating is a simple trivia game for Android devices. On a settings screen I am using a DatePickerDialog for the users birthday. Only when I run it on my Android device (Samsung Galaxy S i9000) or an emulator it crashes when trying to popup the DatePickerDialog.

The code I use is:

```
final TextView dob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_DOB_Info);
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Time dateOfBirth = new Time();
        dateOfBirth.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);
        long dtDob = dateOfBirth.toMillis(true);
        dob.setText(DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy", dtDob));
        Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
        editor.putLong(GAME_PREFERENCES_DOB, dtDob);
        editor.commit();
    }
}, 0, 0, 0);
return dateDialog;
```

Can anyone see if I'm doing something wrong here? When running I get an IllegalArgumentException in that method. I'm using Eclipse to program for Android, but I'm also fairly new to the program (I'm more familiar with Netbeans), I'm still trying to figure out how to properly debug through the Android app.

If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated!
Kind Regards,
Floris

**EDIT:** As per request I added the LogCat lines:

```
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.widget.NumberPicker.setCurrent(NumberPicker.java:362)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDaySpinner(DatePicker.java:487)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.widget.DatePicker.updateSpinners(DatePicker.java:471)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.widget.DatePicker.init(DatePicker.java:467)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:154)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:113)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at com.androidbook.triviaquiz.QuizSettingsActivity.onCreateDialog(QuizSettingsActivity.java:404)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2482)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:882)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2557)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2524)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at com.androidbook.triviaquiz.QuizSettingsActivity$4.onClick(QuizSettingsActivity.java:367)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-16 18:42:22.386: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 18:42:22.414: ERROR/(14248): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

As I'm reading through it now I notice the problem is in the NumberPicker class. Just to be sure, what is the meaning of the number he is expecting here?

Comment: Also I would like to add, if you need to see any of my other code, just ask and I shall provide.

Comment: can you add some DDMS logs of the crash? Which is the line that is throwing the exception?

Comment: Done, I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used `DatePickerDialog` but as far as I can tell, you're using `0, 0, 0` as the year, month of year and day of month parameters. Set these to be something logical like `2011, 9, 16` and see if that helps.

**EDIT** Actually you may have to use `10` for September as I think it conforms to the 0-11 month numbers used by `Calendar`.

Comment: Weird, that actaully did the trick. According to my book 0, 0, 0 should be the default values - whatever the defaults are - for that method. So basicly, if no birthday has been stored before I should manually code a default date? Or maybe get it from a resource file.. Thanks for the help thoughh! If you'd know the reason to why the zero's don't work I'd like to hear it, but I'll mark the answer as correct as my question is solved.

Comment: @Floris: The clue I got was the `IllegalArgumentException` "current should be >= start and <= end" which suggested there was an illegal value for either the year, month or day of month. It was kind of a guess but I wouldn't expect to use year '0' in any Android date / time functions. The month '0' is valid for January as I mention in my edit but, again, I'm not sure if '0' is valid for a day of month value. If you have the time and inclination try varying the values with one at a time being '0' and see which ones fail. And, yes, always provide a default date of some sort in a picker.

Comment: Out of intrest I did as you told me, I varied the parameters with one at a time being '0'. The results are like this, you can set your month to '0' but not your day nor your year. The reason for this is that what you have already mentioned I guess. The months conforms to the 0-11 numbers used by the `Calendar` class.

Comment: @Floris: Interesting to know - I suspected that may be the case. Working with dates and times in Android can be tricky sometimes as some classes behave slightly differently from others. Good luck with your learning. Have fun.